# How to fetch data and insert into another table in same database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 2 tables, one with data and other is blank in same database.

a)- Tables "cusrec" is main and contains data in it.

b)- Tables "order" is empty and I want to insert the data in it.

I tried to fetch data from table "cusrec" and insert it into "order", when I echo, it shows the data of table "cusrec" but it is not inserting into table "order". Both tables are in same database.

Code is:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db('dobhighat');
if(isset($_GET['search'])){
$srch = $_GET['srch'];
$que=mysql_query("select * from cusrec where custid='$srch' OR mobile='$srch'");
$ftch=mysql_fetch_array($que);
$scustid=$ftch['custid'];
$sname=$ftch['name'];
$smobile=$ftch['mobile'];
$totcloth=$ftch['clothpackage'];
if(isset($_POST['confirm']))
{
$ordernum=$_REQUEST['ordernum'];
$orderdate=date('d/m/y');
$ordercloth=$_REQUEST['ordercloth'];
$clothrem=$totcloth-$ordercloth;
$abc=mysql_query("insert into order(custid,name,mobile,totcloth,orderno,orderdate,ordercloth,clothrem)values('$scustid','$sname','$smobile','$totcloth','$ordernum','$orderdate','$ordercloth','$clothrem')");
}
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php $orddate=date('d/m/y'); ?>
<form name="form 1" action="" method="get">
<div align="right"><input type="text" name="srch" placeholder="Search by Id or Mobile" size="25">
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search"></div>
</form>

<form name="form2" action="" method="post">
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td width="103">Order Date</td>
    <td width="94">Customer Id</td>
    <td width="53">Name</td>    
    <td width="71">Mobile</td>
    <td width="144">Order No.</td>    
    <td width="144">No.of Clothes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $orddate; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo @$ftch['custid'];  ?></td>
    <td><?php echo @$ftch['name'];  ?></td>
    <td><?php echo @$ftch['lname'];  ?></td>
    <td><?php echo @$ftch['mobile'];  ?></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="ordernum" required></td>    
    <td><input type="text" name="ordercloth" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td colspan="8"><center><input type="submit" name="confirm" value="Confirm"></center></td></tr>
</table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Help is needed

Comment: Before you go any further, please note that the `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated, and will be removed in the future. You should be using [mysqli](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['confirm']))`.  This will never be true because your form method is `get`.

Comment: ok. Thanks for advice. but what about my problem

Comment: changed it but same problem, not inserting

Comment: Could be a error in the column name..echo $abc , then run the query in phpmyadmin.You will know if the query is correct.

Comment: Adding to what @PatrickQ said, your SQL code is subject to SQL injection. You must sanitize user input before putting it into the database. E.g.: if srch is "'; drop database dobhighat; --" (without the quotes) your database will be gone.

Comment: Also, you must never trust any input from the user, and sanitize whatever you write into the web page. Your code maybe be subject to XSS (e.g.: `<?php echo @$ftch['lname']; ?>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget all I said about the forms and the structure of the document (although it could be useful eventually as I don't know how reliable is that `GET` and `POST`).

I am a dodo and just realized that your table name is `order`. **ORDER is a reserved keyword in SQL** and it's the reason why your SQL statement is incorrect! Just put the name between ` and it will work:

```
$abc=mysql_query("insert into `order`(custid,name,mobile,totcloth,orderno,orderdate,ordercloth,clothrem)values('$scustid','$sname','$smobile','$totcloth','$ordernum','$orderdate','$ordercloth','$clothrem')");
```

Or you may want (if possible) to rename the table in order to avoid confusion and future problems.

This doesn't mean that the code is perfect. You should still look at the recommendations by the other users and the list below, and improve it. Specially the security concerns.

---

Once you fix that, the insert will work; but there are still many things that you need to fix:

- You should not use `mysql` functions and move to `mysqli` or `PDO`.
- You should sanitize all the values that go to the database or to the page:

  - Your code is subject to SQL injection (see comments in question).
  - Your code is subject to XSS (see comments in question).
- The doctype in your page is incorrect (if you want html5, it should be `<!doctype html>` and not `<!doctype>`.
- Names and IDs must not have white spaces in them (read this for name and id notation: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name)
- As stated in other answers, the SQL statement could be improved. The solution that you have may work fine (I don't find any apparent error) but it is not ideal and may present performance problems and other type of problems (e.g.: if two different users have the same phone number).

And there are probably more things that I didn't notice as I just looked quickly through the code.

Comment: Your answer sounds pretty reasonable but much of it goes above head. can u rectify my code and post it as answer please. Thanks for sincere efforts.

Comment: What is the structure of the tables `cusrec` and `order`?

Comment: Where you are seeing, #ftch that is the data in table of cusrec, and where you are seeing $_REQUEST that is the table order where i want to insert the data.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with that comment. what are the field types in each table? I.e.: You are inserting all as varchar but some of them are numeric, is orderdate a date or a varchar?

Comment: @Pawan Done. It was a really simple thing actually, just a `order` instead of order. I should have realized sooner :$

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly from `SQL`

```
INSERT INTO order
       ( custid,
         name,
         mobile,
         totcloth,
         orderno,
         orderdate,
         ordercloth,
         clothrem) 
     SELECT 
            custid,
            name,
            mobile,
            totcloth,
            orderno,
            orderdate,
            ordercloth,
            clothrem
       FROM cusrec
           WHERE custid='$srch' OR mobile='$srch'"
```

;

You just need to match the column with `from table` to `to table`

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect when doing insert into from a select statement.  You don't use the VALUES ( ) clause portion, the select IS the values basis.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of doing an insert from select?  Something like...

```
INSERT INTO ORDER 
   ( custid, name, mobile, otherFields, etc... )
   SELECT same, ordered, fields, as, theInsert
      from custrec where custid='$srch' OR mobile='$srch'
```

The only issue I see with your select where clause is that you could be getting multiple customers via the OR mobile='%srch' and cause duplicate orders.

Comment: I tried it your way but still same issue. Really very disappointed, with my code

Answer (score 0):

I think to insert and fetch the same data we can do it by using the below-mentioned code for PHP MYSQLI.

```
$id=trim($_POST['id']);
$email=trim($_POST['email'];
$env_name=trim($_POST['env_name'];
$sql="INSERT INTO integration (id,email,env_name) VALUES ($id,$email'$envName')";
if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
    $selectSql="SELECT id,email,env_name from integration WHERE id=$id and email='$email'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$selectSql){
        if($result){ 
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            return $row;
        }
    }    
}
```